# Want push notification support even in Doze and App Standby mode for the Emergency System based app

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on the android application, which is useful to send push/alerts to its users for the emergency situations like severe weather, missing persons, colds, floods, earthquakes, etc warnings.

Recently, I have started receiving the complaint from the app users about not receiving the push notifications if they are not opening the app regularly(i.e rarely opens the app).

Kindly help and share if there is any specific service provided by Android for such type of emergency service-related apps through which push notification support can be provided even in Doze and App Standby mode to the Emergency System-based app.

Comment: If you work for a relevant government agency, there may be an emergency alert system available to your government, one that is not tied to a particular phone operating system. Otherwise, use SMS.

Comment: try setting your priority high in notification data. If notification priority is high it will display without delay even if the device is in doze mode.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue , screen was not getting awake for my app notifications when device was in doze mode , only "priority":"high" solved my problem.

```
{
 "message": {
 "token": "fcm_client_token",
 "data": {
    "title": "Hello",
    "body": "Test Message"
 },
"android": {
    "priority": "high"
 }
}
```